# How to create an imageView to open an url?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have an UIImageView(image loaded from remote server at runtime), now i want to open a specific url(say www.google.com) by clicking on this image. i have done this by clicking on button, but i dont know how to do that with imageView.
any suggestion or sample code will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In interface builder (or in your storyboard), select your UIImageView. `Control-drag` from the image to the header file of your class. Select "action", and name it as you want. This will add something like

```
- (IBAction)loadURL:(id)sender;
```

in your header, and

```
- (IBAction)loadURL:(id)sender {
}
```

in your .m file. Insert whatever code you need in this function, and I think you're good to go !

Let me know if you worked your way through.

EDIT : Oops, seems like I talked a bit too quickly, this won't work as you can't add an action to a UIImageView. Another edit coming soon.

EDIT #2 :

Okay, first make sure your image view is "user interaction enabled" in the xib or on your storyboard. Then add an outlet for the image by control-dragging your UIImageView on your header file. Then use the UIResponder methods touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded (and so on) to detect the touch on the image view : add this to your .m file :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == yourImageView)
    {
            NSLog(@"Touched !");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is UIGestureRecognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* recognizer;
recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openLink)];
self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Then implement `openLink` method to open the url.

Comment: Remember to enable user interaction on the imageview!